# Is it possible to integrate an external website into ionic app?

Tags: html, cordova, ionic-framework

I want to create a Ionic app which only shows a external website.
How can I do this?

Thanks for help.

Comment: I should be possible since Ionic is angular, but why doing a full ionic application only for a page? you could use a bare cordova application (the base of what's used by ionic to integrate angular into a mobile application)

Comment: yes it possible with in-app browser and iFrame

Answer (score 1):

I feel you can use **cordova plugin** to opening a link with your app, Also you can use the `custom-url-scheme (cordova-plugin)` So you can open external link on your app as on this way `testapp://path?foo=bar`.

Refer to this : [Here the Link](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme)

================================================================================

So install InAppBrowser:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser

npm install --save @ionic-native/in-app-browser
```

you can call as like:

```
window.open(url, '_system');
```

As described here : [Refer the Link and also document](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser/:)

Comment: I tried this:
`<a class="item" href="#" onclick="window.open('https://youtube.com', '_system', 'location=yes'); return false;">
     open youtube
 </a>`
I tested it with Ionic DevApp, but it opens it into external browser.